# Looking for a Content Management Filter module for drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am looking for a module for content list view for each user, There is a nice module([CMF](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmf)) for D6, but it would be nice to suggest one for D7. I tried lot with google but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability.

**- Filter content by title, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary**

Other features

- Filter all administrative views via AJAX.
- Perform any kind of bulk/mass operations on items in administrative
  views.
- Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
- Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.

Comment: Installed this module, But not sure how to use for each user, Can you please provide some steps or guidance?

Comment: @Jaison Infact I didn't use this module before. But I hope there might be some permission settings for that. Create role and assign users to them for those you want give permissions to access this content management. If I got a chance today, I'll try to do that for you.

Comment: I have tried out the module, there should be some more steps when you use it. Set some permission and also add filter for views(user:current user) then a create block view.

Comment: Glad @Jaison. So are you going to use this module in your site? Is this helpful?